# jquery select several elements with a short code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i want to select several elements with jquery like this:

```
$('p:nth-child(1),p:nth-child(4),p:nth-child(7),p:nth-child(10)')
//nth-child is : 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 and etc
```

I have to select 1 item every 3 items.
How can do this with dynamic code?

Comment: What exactly is "dynamic code" ?

Comment: Is "shor" supposed to be "short"? Question's unclear.

Comment: for example with an array.

Comment: Are these purely children that you are selecting?

Comment: Not clear: you want to select 1 item every 3 items? (and in this case... may your sample is wrong, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, **16**, **19**, **22**, **25**, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select 1 item every 3, you can do the following:

```
$("p:nth-child(3n+1)")
```

For example, here I will set the background color of your "p" items, but only for the 1st, 4th, 7th...:

```
$("p:nth-child(3n+1)").css("background-color", "red");
```

See jsfiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/TjLdy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can store the children you want to select in an array and use a loop to generate your selector:

```
var children = [1,4,7,10,13,17,21,24],
    selector = "";

// Loop through each value in your array, populating your selector string
// Each loop will add "p:nth-child(n)," to your selector string
for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++)
    selector += "p:nth-child(" + children[i] + "),";

// Remove trailing comma
selector = selector.slice(0, -1);
```

This will generate the following `selector` string:

> `"p:nth-child(1),p:nth-child(4),p:nth-child(7),p:nth-child(10),p:nth-child(13),p:nth-child(17),p:nth-child(21),p:nth-child(24)"`

We can now put this into the jQuery selector simply by using:

```
$(selector)
```

Comment: thanks but is there any way to have a dynamic array, i fetch data from database and possible i have 10 element or 1000 element.

Comment: Create your array and then iterate through your data using `array.push(n)` to populate its content. In this case `array` is the name of your array, and `n` is the child number. If, for example, your element's number was `5` and your array like mine here was called `children`, you'd use `children.push(5)`.

Comment: i think i need an Algorithm for Calculation numbers 1,4,7,10 and etc

Comment: @user3760964 you haven't given any information about how you generated those numbers in the first place.

Comment: @user3760964 I have no idea as you haven't given any information about how you generated the numbers you've given in the first place. You also haven't specified what your data is or how it's dynamically generated. We need to see more code before we can answer questions like that.

Comment: It may be a 11 `<p>` or may have 1000 `<p>`

Comment: but i want only select `<p>` that it's nth-child  1,4,7,10,13,17,21,24,27,31,34 and etc

Comment: can you simply add a rule about which items you want to select? The serie you are quoting is `1,4,7,10,13,17,21,24,27,31,34` has no logic!

Comment: the logic is +3, each number +3 from prev number

Comment: So 13 + 3 = 17?
Please add this detail (the +3 rule, not my joke) in your original question and you will have a real answer.

Comment: oh You're right, but logic is +3, i think loop conditions must be change to `+3` instead `++`

Comment: you then can simply use `$("p:nth-child(3n+1)")`. I made an answer in this way